# Excel: Average Ordering Time

Tags: arrays, excel

I've been struggling with this problem all morning.

I have a basic list:

Rows are customers
Columns are all dates with orders
Values are how many orders were placed on said date

[image]

I'm trying to get the average days between orders for each of the customers, but I cannot think of the right way to do this, since each customer ordered on different days.

I can't even think of how to get it to something that looks like this, where each customer row only has the order dates, consecutively. With this I could easily calculate days and average with helper columns.
[image]

Comment: If you have any control of the data collection process here, you would be better off just maintaining your second table from the start

Comment: Why are you showing customer 5 with two identical dates?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  Note that the formula is an array formula.

The formula computes the number of days between each date on which there is an order, and then averages those values.  If this is not what you want, you will need to be specific.

To enter/confirm an **array formula**, hold down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>. If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula seen in the formula bar.

[image]